# Cannot access drawable resource in R.java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I added some PNGs to my `drawable` folder. Now I'm trying to use one of those images but the compiler cannot see them. I'm trying to access the resource `c1` with

```
int res = R.drawable.c1;
```

but compiler cannot find it. Then I looked at `R.java` which looks fine:

```
public final class R {
public static final class attr {
}
public static final class dimen {
    /**  Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. 

     Customize dimensions originally defined in res/values/dimens.xml (such as
     screen margins) for sw720dp devices (e.g. 10" tablets) in landscape here.

     */
    public static final int activity_horizontal_margin=0x7f040000;
    public static final int activity_vertical_margin=0x7f040001;
}
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int br1=0x7f020000;
    public static final int c1=0x7f020001;
    public static final int c10=0x7f020002;
    public static final int c11=0x7f020003;
    public static final int c12=0x7f020004;
    ...
```

I tried to clean and rebuild project but it doesn't solve.

Actually the only resources I see when typing `R.drawable.` seem to be built-in images like `R.drawable.btn_star_big_off`, `R.drawable.btn_star_big_on` and many others (which are NOT inside `R.drawable` static class). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you aren't importing R at all other wise you'll have the wrong R.java

Auto import functions like to import R; erase the import line

Bit of a code example:

```
import android.R; //Shouldn't be anywhere, erase this
```

Comment: It solved, thank you! I didn't know there was more than one R.java file. I was importing android.R.

Comment: Yep, Eclipse LOVES to import it for some reason, caused me a lot of headaches in my early days. Wish the ADT tools caught it or prevented it